# Google reCAPTCHA background CSS color

Tags: css, recaptcha

I'm using Google's reCAPTCHA like this in my html:
`<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey=""></div>` and also adding this script `<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>`.
How can I get rid of the dark grey background? I've tried changing the `background-color` of the `recaptcha_response_field` but it doesn't change anything.

[image: current reCAPTCHA]

Comment: Have you tried changing the reCAPTCHA container with CSS? .g-recaptcha {background: white}

Comment: @Cohen yes I have, that was the first thing I tried

Comment: The reCAPTCHA itself doesn't have a background set beyond its white box and also shouldn't be bigger than its box. Provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by removing the background color for the iframe that Google reCAPTCHA creates.

This is what Google reCAPTCHA creates:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="">
   <div style="width: 304px; height: 78px;">
      <div>
         <iframe title="reCAPTCHA" src="" width="304" height="78" role="presentation" name="a-cvin5ubac2l0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" sandbox="allow-forms allow-popups allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-top-navigation allow-modals allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox"></iframe>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I changed the css for that iframe to `background-color: inherit;`

Comment: I don't see any background color set on that iframe.

Comment: @gre_gor The iframe background color was set globally and it was affecting the Google reCAPTCHA iframe background color. Didn't know the recaptcha would create an iframe.

Comment: By "globaly" you mean your theme's CSS that you didn't show, so anyone of us could only guess at the problem?

Comment: Yes, like I said I didn't know the recaptcha is using an iframe. The code in the html is just `<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey=""></div>`. Did inspect element then found it was using an iframe.

Comment: useless response : there is nowhere to put the background  ...